How to make virtual keyboard show all the time in Godot 4
in godot 4 I am making a UI game. Each scene is loaded with a lot of LineEdits, and the user needs to type letters in them. However, when I exported the game and tested it on a mobile device, I saw that whenever user is done with, for example, line edit 1 and switches focus on line edit 2 to modify it, the keyboard closes and opens again. Because there are hundreds of line edits in the scene, the constant closing and opening of the keyboard becomes really annoying. Is there a way to keep the keyboard open all the time?
Thank you in advance!

I got two possible solutions for your problem.

Use a customn on screen keyboard instead of the virtual keyboard of the system.

For example this
This way you also always know how much space the keyboard uses.

If you want to use the system keyboard you can try to use the DisplayServer

It allows you to check, if the system has a virtual keyboard
DisplayServer.has_feature(DisplayServer.FEATURE_VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD)

Then you can hide and show the keyboard manually:
DisplayServer.virtual_keyboard_show("")
DisplayServer.virtual_keyboard_hide()

Without doing all the work my idea would be to make a node, which handles if the virtual keyboard is shown. (Let's call it KeyboardHandler) On ready it looks for every node in the scene that needs a keyboard by iterating the nodes and checking for 'virtual_keyboard_enabled'. It then sets this property to false to make sure only the handler itself triggers the keyboard. Then it conntects a signal to these nodes (e.g focus_entered) to activate the keyboard if it is not visible:
func on_focus_entered():
    if DisplayServer.virtual_keyboard_get_height() == 0:
        displayserver.virtual_keyboard_show("")

Now the Keyboard is only brought up, if it isn't shown at the moment.

I am new to game dev and to programming in general, i am sorry if my logic is incorrect. If i use the keyboard plugin i think it won't work since I am making the game for less-known language and i am not sure if the Unicodes will align correctly.
To clarify your answer (again it might be stupid to say). I should create a new node that checks all the line edits if they have keyboard disabled and hook the script you provided to it so it shows the keyboard only once?

What if i disable virtual keyboard for all line edits and leave it true for only one of them, which will be focused instantly when the scene is loaded. that way it will remain open all the time?

My phone allows me to close the keyboard on my own. Which would break your game if no element brings it back up again. This is the reason I added the check in the signal. Iterating all line edits is optional for sure. Just thought it would be easier than to do it manually for each node.
